# Accessing PrivateData during Import-Module

Tags: powershell

I want to load the contents of a config.xml file and store it in `$PrivateData` when my module loads. Here is the definition line in my PSD1

```
# Private data to pass to the module specified in ModuleToProcess
PrivateData = @{'Variables'=@{};'Config'=$null}
```

This creates a hashtable with two items. 1) `Variables` is a second hashtable I use to store private variables for my module. 2) Config which will contain the values of a config.xml file. Example XML:

```
<Config>
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
</Config>
```

I can load the xml with the following line:

```
$PrivateData  = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData
$PrivateData.Config = ([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-String)).Config
```

It does not appear that I can access it in my PSM1 file. I CAN wrap it in a Cmdlet like so:

```
Function Initialize-TestModule {
    $PrivateData  = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData
    $PrivateData.Config #= ([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-String)).Config    
}
```

But then the user would have to make a call to `Import-Module` and then a second call to `Initialize-TestModule` which is what I am trying to avoid.

If I put the code in the PSM1 it generates this error when I call `Import-Module`

```
Property 'Config' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\scripts\temp\TestModule\TestModule.psm1:7 char:2
+     $PrivateData.Config = ([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-String) ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

If I try to load in the PSD1 like this:

```
PrivateData = @{'Variables'=@{};'Config'=([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-String)).Config}
```

I get these errors:

```
Import-Module : The module manifest 'C:\scripts\temp\TestModule\TestModule.psd1' could not be processed because it is
not a valid Windows PowerShell restricted language file. Please remove the elements that are not permitted by the
restricted language:
At C:\scripts\temp\TestModule\TestModule.psd1:88 char:26
+ PrivateData = @{'Config'=([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-Strin ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Property references are not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.
At C:\scripts\temp\TestModule\TestModule.psd1:88 char:27
+ PrivateData = @{'Config'=([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-Strin ...
+                           ~~~~~
The type xml is not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.
At C:\scripts\temp\TestModule\TestModule.psd1:88 char:33
+ PrivateData = @{'Config'=([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-Strin ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The command 'Get-Content' is not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.
At C:\scripts\temp\TestModule\TestModule.psd1:88 char:72
+ PrivateData = @{'Config'=([xml](Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml | Out-Strin ...
+                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~
The command 'Out-String' is not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module .\TestModule -force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\scripts\temp...TestModule.psd1:String) [Import-Module], Missing
   MemberException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

In my PSM1 have tried making a call to `Initialize-TestModule` using `Invoke-Command` and `Start-Job` both of which failed. So has anyone managed to access $PrivateData during `Import-Module`?

Comment: $PrivateData.Config #=   => Is that # a typo, or do you really have that in there?

Comment: @mjolinor - yes it was a typo. it is not in my code

Comment: I believe `PrivateData` is supposed to be for config parameters written in the psd1 file (and thus changeable in the psd1, even for signed modules). If you read the configuration from a separate xml file what is the reason for "putting" it into `PrivateData`. You could just put in a module scoped variable named `$Config` or similar. It would then be available to all functions inside that module.

Comment: Code inside the psd1 one is evaluated using a very limited subset of powershell. This is the problem you are facing. Instead of this approach, you shoudl create a ps1 file that you then insert into the nestedmodules part of the psd1. This will autoinvoke the code upon import-module.

Answer (score 7):

You will likely need to access the private data using the $MyInvocation variable. However, I've only gotten it to work by calling it from within a function. To load it to a variable in the PSM1 file I call the function from there. I found out about this from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9620af9a-0323-460c-b3e8-68a73715f99d/module-scoped-variable?forum=winserverpowershell.

```
function Get-PD
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Begin{}
    Process
    {
        $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData
    }
    End{}
}

$MyPD = Get-PD
```